# how to make image slider like google play

Tags: android

when you go to any application page on google play store, you find :

1. the logo of the application
2. right to it there is the name of the app.
3. under it there is 5 to 6 screens about the app activities.

you can slide these images right and left.

i wonder, how could i do that?

#### what i have tried

1. i thought that image gallery is my goal. so, i went to official google document about it and i found that it is no longer support.
2. i tried making 5 image views in a row in relative layout but it is really hard to mangage, them. i believe that there is another solution

is there another solution please?

Comment: have a look at ViewPager.

Comment: ViewPager or HorizontalScrollView are there try use anyone of it

Comment: @Emender what is horizontal scroll view? is it a predifiend view in eclipse?

Comment: HorizontalScrollView = http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html

Comment: not eclipse predefined in android

Answer (score 0):

Okay I'll try and break this down as much as I can.

1. LinearLayout (Vertical) - this contains ALL and everything you see on the screen.

   a. RelativeLayout - this has the logo, name and buy/download button

   b. ScrollView - this is below the Relative Layout, this has the screenshots, descriptions etc. inside this a LinearLayout(Vertical)

   i. Image Scroll (horizontal) - [HorizontalScollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html), [YUI Library](http://www.wfimc.org/public/js/yui/3.3.0/examples/scrollview/scrollview-horiz.html), google it, there's tons

   ii. Other views: texts/images/rating etc.

It's actually straight forward if you break it down in a step by step.

**EDIT**

Here's the best Library for the Image Scroll: [**TwoWay Lib**](https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view)

Comment: they have a scroll view with centerlock to always center the image on the screen